# How do I fill an m x n matrix with random numbers if I am given the sums of individual rows and columns?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, matrix, random

I need to write a Java program to generate a matrix with 3 rows and 5 columns such that:
(1) The sum of each row is R.
(2) The sums of columns are C1, C2, C3, C4, C5.

Satisfying any one of these conditions is pretty straightforward, e.g. to satisfy condition (1) I'll generate 5 random numbers between 0 and 1, calculate their sum, and then scale each of them up such that their sum is equal to R.

Or I can satisfy condition (2) by generating 3 random numbers and scaling them up so that their sum is C1 (or C2, C3, etc.)

But I have no idea how to satisfy *both* of these conditions together.

If it matters, all the numbers will be positive. They may or may not be integers.

Comment: Could you clarify if R is an input or an arbitrary number ? (as in, the sums of columns must be the *same*, or, equal to a given input)

Comment: R, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5 are inputs.

Comment: @NewAccount They shouldn't all be inputs since there's an implicit constraint that Sum(C_i) = 3R, i=1..5. If you leave it to end-users, they're going to screw that up with infeasible inputs.

Comment: Do the elements of the array need to be positive?

Answer (score 2):

R1, R2, R3 are the sums of each row. They are defined to be R

```
R1 = R2 = R3 = R
```

E is everything. The sum of all rows, and the sum of all columns.

```
E = 3*R;
E = C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5;
3 * R = C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5;
R = (C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5) / 3;
R = C1/3 + C2/3 + C3/3 + C4/3 + C5/3
```

By definition, you can fill each cell by the Column sum divided by the number of rows.

If the inputs are such that `3 * R ≠ C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5` there is no solution.

Here is demonstration on why you can always balance 2 pairs at a time.

Using C values of 5,9,13,7,8:

```
 |  A |  B | C  | D  | E  |
 +----+----+----+----+----|
1|1.67|  3 |4.33|2.33|2.67|
2|1.67|  3 |4.33|2.33|2.67|
3|1.67|  3 |4.33|2.33|2.67|
 -------------------------/
```

Select pairs of distance 1, moving rightward one step until arriving at the last column Note that you wrap around at E->A

```
AB,BC,CD,DE,EA;
```

Then all pairs of distance 2,

```
AC,BD,CE,DA,EB,
```

you'd repeat as long as your pairs are of distance < w/2.

Then, for each horizontal pair, you need an equal and opposite pair. To be found in the same process.
1:2,2:3,3:1.

(for any unordered pair P, the distance between the two columns is always equal or smaller than half the width of the matrix. We've selected every right handed pair by starting at every column and grabbing the pair of increasing distance

You have `(int)w/2 * (int)h/2` unique unordered pairs for any matrix.
(this is a truncation not a rounding)

Here is the complete code, with a sanity check:

```java
import java.util.Random;

class MySolver{

    public static double[][] initMatrix(int w, int h, double[] C) {
        double[][] matrix = new double[w][h];
        for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j)
                matrix[i][j] = C[i] / h;
        return (matrix);    
    }

    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        int w = 5;
        int h = 3;
        double[] C = { 5, 9, 13, 7, 8 };
        double[][] matrix = initMatrix(w, h, C);
        Random rand = new Random();
        double delta;

        for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j)
                System.out.printf("|%5.2f", matrix[j][i]);
            System.out.printf("|%n");
        }
        System.out.printf("%n%n%n");

        for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < w / 2; ++j) {
                for (int k = 0; k < h; ++k) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < h / 2; ++l) {
                        delta = rand.nextDouble()  * Math.min(matrix[i][k], matrix[(i+j+1) % w][(k+l+1) % h]);;
                        System.out.printf("%5.2f%n", delta);
                        matrix[i][k] -= delta;
                        matrix[(i+j+1) % w][(k+l+1) % h] -= delta;
                        matrix[i][(k+l+1) % h] += delta;
                        matrix[(i+j+1) % w][k] += delta;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%n%n%n");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
            delta = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
                delta += matrix[j][i];
                System.out.printf("|%5.2f", matrix[j][i]);
            }
            System.out.printf("|  %.2f%n", delta);
        }
        System.out.printf("%n");
        for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
            delta = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j)
                delta += matrix[i][j];
            System.out.printf("|%5.2f", delta);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
| 1.67| 3.00| 4.33| 2.33| 2.67|
| 1.67| 3.00| 4.33| 2.33| 2.67|
| 1.67| 3.00| 4.33| 2.33| 2.67|



 1.59
 2.47
<REDACTED for brevity>
 0.09
 0.51



| 0.16| 6.05| 2.76| 2.09| 2.94| 14.00
| 1.63| 2.36| 8.37| 0.08| 1.55| 14.00
| 3.21| 0.59| 1.87| 4.83| 3.51| 14.00

| 5.00| 9.00|13.00| 7.00| 8.00
```

Comment: I want the numbers to be randomly generated though. I certainly don't want each cell to contain the exact same value.

Comment: That's not the question you posed and that's not an exercise worthy of a question.
Start with the perfect solution and move some numbers around in a balanced way.
X = random, A1 += X; A2 -= X; B1 -= X; B2 += X;

Comment: If you're adding and subtracting the same value in pairs, that's not going to work with odd cardinalities. Also, OP's question has 8 degrees of freedom, while your proposal falls short of that. You're right that R is redundant given the C's.

Comment: That's not true. The pairs don't have to be consecutive and you don't have to limit yourself to only one pair per cell. You could (and should) balance values with all possible pairs. . .

I fail to see the other degrees of freedom. The problem explicitely states 1 matrix with fixed size. 6 Variables, one of which is redundant. The width and height could be adjusted accordingly, just switch the constant 3 in my math with the height variable.

Comment: You fail to see the other degrees of freedom because you don't seem to understand the concept of degrees of freedom. The matrix is a table containing r * c entries. Given all the row and column totals, once you specify (r-1) * (c-1) values the remaining values can all be solved for algebraically. In other words, for a 3*5 situation where the row/column totals are known, 8 of the 15 values are free to vary but the remaining 7 are then completely determined by the available information. And no, you can't do pairwise adjustments on an odd number of values.

Comment: I've updated my answer with pairwise ajustment. You're right, I was misunderstanding the concept of degrees of freedom. It took me a second but thanks for the explanation. How would you express that the bounds for later defined values in the first 8 to be tighter ? (since they cannot be negative, each row less the last column must have a sum strictly less than R)

Comment: It's a non-trivial problem, and I don't have a solution other than acceptance/rejection techniques - if I did, I'd have posted it as my own answer. I downvoted you yesterday because until you can show an actual working solution to that sub-problem this is not yet an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238367/discussion-between-sybog64-and-pjs).